# How do I turn off the notification sound for when apps request the current location

Tags: notifications, 8.0-oreo, location-services

Today, my HTC 10 was updated to Oreo 8.0.0.

Now, whenever an app requests my location, I get the location icon appearing, and a default notification sound plays. "System UI: Finding Location" is what the notification displays.

The sound never played before the update.

I've looked everywhere to try to turn this notification sound off, and I cannot find it.

I did go to Settings > Sounds and Notifications > Advanced > Notifications. When I see the list of apps, I've also clicked on the options menu to include System apps. I assumed I had found it with Location Services, and turned off "Allow Sound" which was turned on. It did not turn off the sound. I also restarted the phone.

I would like to turn off the sound while continuing to allowing apps to request my location. For example, when I go into Instagram, or the camera, I get the notification. I don't care if it shows me the icon for a second, but the sound has got to go.

---

Edit: Verizon Wireless is my carrier. I didn't think that was relevant, but once I found the solution, I realized it was.

Answer (score 6):

Go to Settings > Sounds and Notifications > Advanced > Notifications.

Click on the three dots up in the right corner and tap **Show System**.

Scroll down to **System UI**.

Under *Categories*, tap on **VZW**, then tap on **Importance**, select **Medium: No sound**.

---

Why is the GPS location notification in the VZW category of notifications? I don't understand.

I debugged by setting the category sounds to one other than the default, and when going into an app that requested the GPS location, I heard that unique sound, and that let me pin it down to the VZW category.

I do not know what other notifications fall into the VZW category, but they won't be making a sound when the notification shows anymore.

Comment: Thank you!!!  Fellow Verizon HTC 10 user.  This was driving me crazy!!!  I actually got to the last step by myself, but didn't know you could tap the categories for even further options.  A million more thanks!